# Why use HTTP_HOST and PHP_SELF to build a URL?

Tags: php

I'm picking up the pieces after another dev and found this snippet.  It has no comments and I'm having a hard time dissecting why it exists.  It is lovingly found in requests.php

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$query = !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : null;
$url = !empty($query) ? "http://$host$self?$query" : "http://$host$self";
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
I was able to understand that the URL was parsed, but I couldn't understand why (which should be the essence of any code documentation).  I don't think this necessitates a down vote.  The code and question were provided, and I left this open so as to not guide the answer.  The myriad of responses for such a question demonstrate that this wasn't a bad thing to do.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Don't you understand what `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` or don't you understand why anyone would assign that to `$host`? I could understand both, but the first could be answered by a simple search on Google, and the second by looking at the rest of your code to see how these variables are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

It is attempting to parse the URL of the currently executing page. So:

http://example.com/somepage.php?foo=bar

Would be:

```
$host = 'example.com';
$self = '/somepage.php';
$query = 'foo=bar';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; // returns the host of the site
$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // returns the current page

/*
 * a ternary condition asking if the URL has a query string, 
 * if so make $query equal to the string, 
 * if not make $query null
 */    
 $query = !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : null;

/* 
 * a ternary condition checking if $query is empty
 * if it isn't, concatenate the three elements
 * if it is only concatenate two of them
 */
$url = !empty($query) ? "http://$host$self?$query" : "http://$host$self";
```

Answer (score 0):

If your page was located at http://www.test.com/test.php?x=y&1=2

> $query would = 'x=y&1=2'

and...

> $url would = 'http://www.test.com/test.php?x=y&1=2'

This could be used for displaying certain content when you're on certain pages for example, or only if a query exists, etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; // gets host header
$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // filename of current file
$query = !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : null; // if the query string is not empty (query string is stuff after the `?` in the URL) set `$query` to that else set it to null
$url = !empty($query) ? "http://$host$self?$query" : "http://$host$self"; // if `$query` is not empty print a url with the host the name of the current file and the query string else just print a url with the host and current file
```

Answer (score 0):

The domain name of the server

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

The script currently being executed.

```
$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

if the server query string is not null, then query will equal the server's query string, else query will equal null.

```
$query = !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : null;
```

if query is not null, then url will equal `$host.$self.$query`, else it not have a query string on the end of it.

```
$url = !empty($query) ? "http://$host$self?$query" : "http://$host$self";
```